# specialize a c++ template function when two types are the same

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

My use case is the following. Given an object I want a readable means of determining if that object is a subclass of another object. Obviously at the core is a call to `dynamic_cast`, but I want something more readable. So I have the following:

```
template <typename C, typename T>
bool isInstanceOf(const T& t) noexcept {
    if (typeid(t) == typeid(C)) {
        return true;
    }
    if (dynamic_cast<const C*>(&t) != nullptr) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This works as intended, but if I make a call where C and T are in fact the same type, I get a compiler warning on the dynamic_cast because the compiler knows it will never return null. This leads me to my question which is: can I write a specialized version of this that simply returns true if C and T are in fact the same type.

I tried the obvious

```
template <typename C>
inline bool isInstanceOf(const C& t) noexcept {
    return true;
}
```

but that gives me an error of "Call to 'isInstanceOf' is ambiguous."

This isn't really a high-priority item as I would never actually call `isInstanceOf<B>(b)` where I know b is of type B, but I have it in my unit tests for completeness and would like to see if there is a way to get the compiler to optimize it out without giving the warning.

In case it help, here is the warning message I receive:

```
In file included from Tests/rtti.cpp:15:0:
.build/Linux-x86_64/include/kss/util/rtti.hpp: In instantiation of ‘bool kss::util::rtti::isInstanceOf(const T&) [with C = {anonymous}::B; T = {anonymous}::B]’:
Tests/rtti.cpp:81:9:   required from here
.build/Linux-x86_64/include/kss/util/rtti.hpp:61:40: warning: the compiler can assume that the address of ‘t’ will never be NULL [-Waddress]
     if (dynamic_cast<const C*>(&t) != nullptr) {
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: `std::is_same_v`? In C++17 without any SFINAE tricks doable. Just a `if constexpr`.

Comment: Actually you all can hold off on giving me answers on this one. It looks like c++14 has eliminated the need for me to have this method at all as is_base_of, is_convertible, and is_same may do what I want. I'm going to try a couple of things, then will update my post.

Comment: Neither of these check for the runtime type though.

Comment: Thanks @tkausl, I just realized the same thing. So it looks like when I move my library to C++17 I'll be able to do what I want, but for C++14 I may just suppress the warning in my test code since the code actually does what it should, just not as efficiently as it could.

Comment: In the meantime, I can replace the `if (typeid(t) == typeid(C))` with the slightly better `if (std::is_base_of<C, T>::value)`. That doesn't suppress the warning, but it does remove the need for the dynamic_cast in a few more cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have C++17, you might use `if constexpr`:

```
template <typename C, typename T>
bool isInstanceOf(const T& t) noexcept {
    if constexpr (std::is_same<T, C>::value) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return dynamic_cast<const C*>(&t) != nullptr;
    }
}
```

Prior C++17, overloads and SFINAE (or tag dispatching) might do the job:

```
template <typename C>
bool isInstanceOf(const C& t) noexcept {
    return true;
}

template <typename C, typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<C, T>::value, bool>
isInstanceOf(const T& t) noexcept {
    return dynamic_cast<const C*>(&t) != nullptr;
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly and does exactly what I want. (Note that I did have to fix a small syntax error in your C++14 version.) Thank you very much. I will patch my library and republish it tonight.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked and mainly for fun but... what about a couple of template overloaded functions as follows

```
template <typename T>
bool isIstanceOf (T const &) noexcept
 { return true; }

template <typename>
bool isIstanceOf (...) noexcept
 { return false; }
```

that you have to call **explicating** the type `T` ?

But is more "is-convertible-to" than "is-instance-of".

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
bool isIstanceOf (T const &) noexcept
 { return true; }

template <typename>
bool isIstanceOf (...) noexcept
 { return false; }

struct A
 { };

struct B : public A
 { };

int main()
 {
   A  a;
   B  b;

   std::cout << isIstanceOf<A>(a) << std::endl;    // print 1
   std::cout << isIstanceOf<A>(b) << std::endl;    // print 1
   std::cout << isIstanceOf<B>(a) << std::endl;    // print 0
   std::cout << isIstanceOf<B>(b) << std::endl;    // print 1
   std::cout << isIstanceOf<int>(a) << std::endl;  // print 0
   std::cout << isIstanceOf<int>(b) << std::endl;  // print 0
 }
```

Comment: An interesting answer but, as you mention, isn't quite what I'm looking for. Basically I need something that tells me if a dynamic cast will succeed or not.

Comment: I should perhaps note as an "aside" that I use this mostly for looking at test results. I have another wrapper around a dynamic_cast that I call "as" which just returns the dynamic_cast after first checking for null pointers. I use that much more than isInstanceOf.